# dynamic rendering in express using loop won't work

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have bunch of static file, they are named article1, article2 and so on. So I know it worked when I do

```
app.get('/this-is-my-article-routes', (req, res) => {
        res.render('article1');
});
```

but it's too tedious and has lots of repeated code. I tried this but it doesn't work?

```
const articleArr = [
    'this-is-my-article-routes'
];

for (i = 0; i<9; i++) {
    app.get(`/${articleArr[i]}`, (req, res) => {
        res.render(`article${i}`);
    });
}
```

Is this even possible? or there's something wrong with my codes?

Comment: why down vote? strange

Comment: Your `i` variable will be wrong with the route handler is actually run.  If you use `for (let i = 0; i < 9; i++)`, it will probably work because `let` in a `for` loop creates a separate `i` variable for each invocation of the loop so it will retain the proper value when the event handle is run some time in the future.

Answer (score 1):

```
how about simple solution using query params 
app.get('articleArr/:id', (req, res) => {
        res.render('article/'+req.params.id);
    });
```

Comment: The concept is a good one, but the parameter you are passing to `res.render()` is wrong.  You need to construct a string.

Answer (score 0):

Does your array `articleArr` contains 10 elements?

I think, the better way to do this would be:

```
var articleList = [ 'first', 'second', 'third']
app.get('/:article', (req, res) {
    var articleName = req.params.article
    var index       =  articleList.indexOf(articleName)
    if (index == -1) {
        // No Aricle Found
    }
    res.render(`articles$(index)`)
})
```

This code will also work fine but it is not the recommended one.

```
var articleList = ['first', 'second']
articleList.forEach(function(value){
    app.get('/'+value, (req, res) => {
        res.status(200).json({
            value: value
        })
    })
})
```

Comment: yes. but what is :article? the title should not be the filename.

Comment: If the user will request for /first endpoint you will be rendering articles0. You can store `'this-is-my-article-routes'` as first element in articleList and render articles0.